# facebook sharer.php description

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-sharer

I have read a lot on meta tags (og:title, og:type, og:image, og:url, og:description) however that is for a url which is of different domain. How can I get "about" description of a fb page to be displayed when the page link is shared via sharer.php? 
For instance, if you visit this page link, it will allow you to share it on the wall but with no description. Is there a solution to this? can the "about page details" be added in the description before sharing the link via sharer.php?
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=facebook.com/WillSmith

Comment: well...did you try with the about section?

Comment: Yes... same result.. https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=facebook.com/MicrosoftIndia/info